# Recently my NFS RAID performance has gone from very good to basically unusable

Tags: raid, nfs, zfs, file-transfer

First, thanks for any help anyone is willing to give!

I have two ubuntu 20.04 servers with two different software RAIDs on them. One is music and movies (RAID6) and the other is personal docs and photos (RAIDZ2).

I mount and manage these from my laptop `uname -r` gives `5.9.1-arch1-1`. Over the past 6 months, I bought a new router and have been getting really fast transfer speeds. Typically every file starts at 250MB/s and descends down to a plateau of ~50MB/s(RAID6) or ~70MB/s (RAIDZ2). Great, I can transfer a bluray file in about 2-3 minutes from the file browser or command line without issue.

In the past week or so, file transfers to either NAS start at 250MB/s then descend quickly past the usual plateau, the RAID6 plateaus at 5MB/s and the RAIDZ2 down at 19MB/s. On top of this, when doing file transfers within the file browser, the files will hang at 0% remaining for a 3-10 minutes. I assume this is some recent update on the client as these systems are managed on two different servers with two different softwares (mdadm vs zfs).

`mount` output (client side) for RAID6 and ZFS servers in order

`192.168.192.175:/mnt/Share/raid6 on /home/name/raid6 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.192.164,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.192.175)`

`192.168.192.201:/mnt/raidz2 on /home/name/raidz2 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.192.164,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.192.201)`

`/etc/exports` on the RAID6 is
`/mnt/Share/raid6 192.168.192.1/24(rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)`

`/etc/exports` on the RAIDZ2 is
`/mnt/raidz2    192.168.192.1/24(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)`

Both `mdadm --detail` and `zpool status -v` come back clean for both RAIDs and have more than 50% disk available.

TL;DR - healthy network RAIDS both showed abrupt dramatic decline in write performance

also posted [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1935153#p1935153)